# GCC warn for non-freed heap blocks

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

So the question is simple is there a way to tell the GCC that I want to get warned if I do not free a heap allocated block? I know that we can have non-freed blocks for some purposes/we already reached end of program or something like that.

```
int main(){
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

If I can get a warning even for this it would be awesome.

Comment: GCC? of course not. Valgrind yes

Comment: @Idos I know Valgrind can check but if there was a way to get the warnings before than crash it would be really awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a possible job for GCC to do. Static analysis cannot prove that a free is forgotten, that's the job of run-time analysers like [valgrind's](http://valgrind.org/) memcheck, or eventually `gcc -fsanitize=leak`, which I haven't seen there [yet](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html), only with [clang -fsanitize=leak](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html).

But you won't get a compile-time warning, even when gcc or clang supports it. It will be a run-time warning.

Comment: But isn't the runtime a bit different with each situation. So can it be not proven because it would require too much time to check all states of program?

Comment: `-fsanitize=leak` is only an optimization, AFAIK you can just compile with `-fsanitize=address` which works fine with gcc.

Comment: Yakup: Yes the run-time will only catch the leaks in the testsuite, not the uncovered ones.

Marc: -fsanitize=address will not really catch a leak, -fsanitize=memory does, but leak and valgrind are best.

Comment: @rurban Did you actually try compiling the OP's testcase with `gcc -fsanitize=address`? If you run the result, it prints "ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks"...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Oh, that's cool. I was one of at the very first AddressSanitizer users, but they added much more useful catches in the last years, I don't know of.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler cannot predict and warn for non-freed blocks. This is runtime job, not compile time. You can implement your own malloc-free-check subsystem or modify memory management library.

Comment: I know that a compiler can't check if the memory is allocated from heap but I taught there would be an attribute that used by "heap allocating functions". that would be possible.

Comment: I suppose there are diagnostic implementations of memory management. There must be extra info to each allocated block for the address in program where it is allocated (with `malloc`). Then you can call some `_mem_leak` function at program termination which will scan for all non-freed blocks.